# Labview 2d array indicator

Tags: labview

I must be missing something obvious:

I'd like to add an indicator for a 2d array to a vi. The display should have 2 columns and 20 rows to display a 20x2 uint16 array.

When I create an array view and add a numeric indicator, I can extend the array by extending the array with the mouse, but it keeps having only 1 dimension, either horizontally or vertically.

This is Labview 2016 on Linux. What do I miss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just drag the mouse in the Index display to the left and increase the dimension.
[image]

or:

[image]

See video tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWSdQ74pejo